# What site should I ask about mysterious pixel line on Windows-running laptop?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What site should I ask a question about a mysterious pixel line on a Windows-running laptop?

I am curious because I can only notice the line in mid-brightness colors. It's a very new laptop... only it has been dropped once.

Comment: "only dropped once" well there's your problem. Laptops aren't really meant to be dropped. You should place them on surfaces gently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably it's a defect in your monitor, and you should ask your supplier instead of a Stack Exchange site. Laptops aren't meant to be dropped and this could break the warranty.

In general, [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) is Stack Exchange's site about computer hardware. It does have questions like [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1296309/442468) about other monitor problems.

Comment: "Laptops aren't meant to be dropped and this could break the warranty." Or the laptop :)